# How can I add a Background Tile to a transparent Image?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to add a tiled background to a transparent image.

According to the docs this should do it:

```
convert test.png -texture paper.png result.png
```

I also tried other variations (with -composite, -flatten, -tile, etc.) but result.png is either still transparent or just gets a white background.

ImageMagick-6.8.7-5 on Windows.

Comment: Can you add your ImageMagick version / platform?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with

```
convert -size 4096x4096 tile:paper.png test.png -flatten result.png
```